# how to pass javascript array to jade template ? script written inside jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

this is my drop down,

```
select.selectpicker(onchange='', id='drop_banch', data-live-search='true')
   option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Select Branch
      for result in '#{b_name}'
        option(value='#{result.b_name}') #{result.b_name}
```

AJAX Call,
    script.
    function jsFunction() {
        var client = document.getElementById('drop_client');
        var c_name = client.options[client.selectedIndex].text;
        var data = {};
        data.c_name = c_name;

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/dispatch_item',

        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
            for (var k in data) {
                var b_name = [];
                b_name.push(data[k].client_name);
            }
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Ajax error!');
            console.log('process error');
        }
    });
```

and my problem is i cant use the 'b_name' array outside the script. how can i access that?

Comment: try declaring var b_name = [];  outside the ajax call,

Comment: no bro.. not working!